# What AR technology are they using here, and how come they can access the camera without even promting for camere access?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

On thing that I find a bit troublesome with AR on the web, is the fact that you have to ask for camera access each time you enter a AR experience. Then I found this example on IOS which does not prompt: https://www.charpstar.co/

How do they do it? I seems like I am accessing a native environment and leaving the browser...

Best regards
Fredrik